# How to deal with an attribute whose class is data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-sp

I have a silly question about datasets. I have been working with sp objects, using external functions for every column to calculate landscape metrics. Once I consolidated my data, I got this configuration

```
sapply(df@data,class)

numeric"    "numeric" "data.frame" "data.frame"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "integer"    "numeric"     "factor"
```

As you can see columns 3 and 4 are of `data.frame` class. I tried to keep with others processings, but I got issues with those attributes. Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you trying to do that's causing you issues?

Comment: is your desired outcome to have these as numeric types instead? If so, you can do `df$var <- as.numeric(df$var)` Otherwise, could you give more context into your issue?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Once I tried to apply other function (e.g. discretize) to these variables, don't work. I tried as well to transform variables (as.numeric) but no changes at all.

Comment: You need to give us a bit more detail and example data. What does `str( df@data )` look like? What's wrong with the `"data.frame"` classes, why can't you use them? What do you want them to be?

Comment: Thanks for your support. I used `as.numeric(unlist(df@data))` and it worked.